# Need Help Creating Object from JSON

Tags: vue.js

I am brand new to Vue, and I am having trouble with changing a JSON into an object. Here is an example of my code.

```html
<template>
<div class="characters">

<template>
   <div class="stat-card">
     <v-container class="mx-2">
       <v-row>
         <v-col cols="4">
           <v-text-field
             v-model="characterID"
             outlined
             label="Search for a character by ID"
             placeholder="Enter a numeric character ID"
             type="text"
             append-icon="mdi-send"
             @click:append="fetchCharacter(characterID)"
             @keyup.enter="fetchCharacter(characterID)"
           >
           </v-text-field>
         </v-col>
       </v-row>
       <v-row>
         <v-card flat>
           <v-card-title>Results:</v-card-title>
           <v-card-text>
             <pre>{{ characterData.id }}</pre>
           </v-card-text>
         </v-card>
       </v-row>
     </v-container>
   </div>
 </template>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      characterID: undefined,
      characterDataJSON: {},
      characterData: {},
      statSlider: [
        { attribute: 'example1' },
        { attribute: 'example2' },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchCharacter(id) {
      const numericID = parseInt(id, 10);
      const requestURI = `/character/${numericID}`;
      const method = 'GET';

      await this.$http({ url: requestURI, data: null, method })
        .then((resp) => {
          this.characterDataJSON = JSON.stringify(resp.data.data, null, '\t');
          this.characterData = JSON.parse(this.characterDataJSON);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          const msg = { error: 'character not found' };
          this.characterDataJSON = JSON.stringify(msg, null, '\t');
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Right now

```
{{ characterData.id }}
```

is giving me the id, however. I want to do something like this:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      characterID: undefined,
      characterDataJSON: {},
      characterData: {},
      statSlider: [
        { attribute: 'example1', value: characterData.id },
        { attribute: 'example2' },
      ],
    };
  },
```

When I do this though, I get characterData is undefined.

> error  'characterData' is not defined  no-undef

My end goal is to be able to use characterData in my sliders, dropdown menus, and etc... I have been trying different things, but I am so new to Vue I am not sure where to begin. Does anyone know what I should be searching?

Comment: simply dont use `JSON.stringify`, its not needed

Answer (score 0):

`statSlider` should be a computed property as follows :

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      characterID: undefined,
      characterDataJSON: {},
      characterData: {},
    };
  },
computed:{
    statSlider(){
       return [
        { attribute: 'example1', value: this.characterData.id },
        { attribute: 'example2' },
      ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.` in your `data` properties as well as in `methods` and `computed`.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      characterID: undefined,
      characterDataJSON: {},
      characterData: {},
      statSlider: [
        { attribute: 'example1', value: this.characterData.id },
        //            here ======>      ^^^^^
        { attribute: 'example2' },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Not doing so will give you an `undefined` error. If the code you've posted is exactly as is in your project (no typos), that's may be your issue.

Also, because `characterData` is coming from an `async` call, I would recommend using `??` or `||` to coalesce to a default value before it's been set by the call. However, since you've defined `characterData` as `{}`, `characterData.id` should automatically be `undefined` instead of giving an error. I just find it better to be explicit, and that would let you give a default.